# Error 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 38619: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, file, character-encoding

I get the following error message

'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 38619: character maps to

when trying to read a file in a directory, despite specifying its encoding.

```
print("contents: ",open('data/text.txt',encoding = "cp1252").read())
```

Comment: That says, whatever you think, that the file is not encoded as Windows-1252. Do you have a good reason for believing it is? The quickest way to resolve this is to download Notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) and open the file in that. It is exceptionally good at guessing encodings and will show you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I used the command print(open('data/text.txt',"r")) to find the encoding

Comment: That can't possibly tell you the encoding. A charmap encoding like Windows-1252 can only be guessed at. The message you report that the first 38,618 bytes of the file were consistent with the encoding you declared, which could mean it was all `ascii` or `latin-1` up to that point because they are validity-subsets of `cp1252`. The `open()` call in your comment specifies UTF-8 because that is the default. I predict that if your code actually reads that file as UTF-8, you will encounter an encoding problem very much sooner  than position 38,619.